# Undefined method in devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, belongs-to

I'm fairly new to rails and trying to add a belongs_to association to my Devise User model.
The error I get when trying to render the view:

NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#edit
undefined method `department_id' for #

This error is occurring on the collection_select in my view. Isn't this method provided by the belongs_to association?

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  belongs_to :department
end
```

Edit view

```
%h2
  Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %p
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.text_field :email
  %p
    = f.label :department
    %br/
    = collection_select(resource_name, :department_id, Department.all, :id, :name)
  %p
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really should work, I have a belongs_to :business on my devise User model and an analogous collection_for_select works great. The only thing I can think of is that maybe your migrations haven't run and you don't have the user.department_id column yet?

Comment: You were right, the problem is I changed the migration after it had already been run on this database. I feel stupid now.

Comment: Ah, glad it worked! Sometimes a second pair of eyes makes all the difference ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @njorden, be sure to do the following:

1. migrate to add `department_id` to your users table
2. `attr_accessible :department_id` to allow mass assignment via edit registration form

Answer (score 0):

That looks backwards. `collection_select` would be appropriate for the `has_many` side of the association. Note that the semantic hint here is that when an object `belongs_to` another object it's singular. There is no collection involved. You ask for `department` and get back a one object. From the other direction, if your `Department` was set to `has_many :users` then asking for users would give you a list of users.

Take a look at the [docs for `select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select). They give a simple example of what you're trying to do with departments (in the form of choosing an author for a blog post).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my case, I had a similar issue.  Initially each user had a department with a department_id, then I moved to a has_many, and forgot to remove the department_id from user.  Solution was to delete department_id off of user.